# multiple data source in spring boot - jdbcTemplate is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, datasource

I am using multiple data sources in my spring boot project as,

> application.properties

```
#first DB
integration.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port1/my_sample_schema1
integration.datasource.username=username
integration.datasource.password=password
integration.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
integration.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
integration.jpa.show-sql=true


#second DB
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port2/my_sample_schema2
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

> DBConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    
      
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "integrationDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "integration.datasource")
    public DataSource integrationDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource mainDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "integrationJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate integrationJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("integrationDataSource") DataSource integrationDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(integrationDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name ="mainJdbcTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate mainJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource mainDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(mainDataSource);
    }
}
```

> SampleClass.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SampleClass{

    @Autowired
    private  JdbcTemplate mainJdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("integrationJdbcTemplate")
    private static JdbcTemplate integrationTemplate;
    
    public static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select * from tableA";

    public List<SampleDto> getDBData(SampleDto fileData) {
        List<SampleDto> data = null;
        try {
            data = integrationTemplate.query(
                    SampleClass.SELECT_QUERY, new Object[] { param1, param2 },
                    new SampleDataMapper());
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

In the **SampleClass.java** am getting *integrationTemplate* as *null* . Why is this so? *mainJdbcTemplate* is working. But *integrationTemplate* is getting as null and not able to excute the query.

Comment: Try without the `@Qualifier` and with the exact same name as the defined `@Bean` (integrationJdbcTemplate) UPDATE, you can't use a `static` field with `@Autowired`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a `static` field with [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)

With `@Autowired` fields are injected right after the construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) for more information about Ioc and Bean injection.

Remove the `static`:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("integrationJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate integrationTemplate;
```

Of course, you can do this but **it's not recommended**:

```
private static JdbcTemplate integrationTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setIntegrationJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate integrationTemplate){
    SampleClass.integrationTemplate = integrationTemplate;
}
```

## Autowiring by Name

If you use the exact same name as the one that you used for the bean initialization you don't need to put the `@Qualifier`, just use as:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate integrationJdbcTemplate;
```

And that's because Spring knows which bean to inject. If you have more beans of the same type then it will throw `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` then you define it with the `@Qualifier`.

I would also suggest marking your fields as `final`, just for good practices.

Comment: it helped..!!! static was the problem